# AChartEngine - refreshing the chart during usb communication

Tags: android, achartengine

I refresh the chart in Timer. When the function refresh chart only everything is OK,  but when I add code to the USB communication the graph is updated (once) only when the function is complete.

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
        data[0][i] = getRandom(0, 20);
        data[1][i] = (i + 1);
    }

    lineGraph.refreshChart(data[0], data[1]);
    if (complete[0]) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        return;
    }

    }
}, 100, 100);

// without the following two lines works fine
usbPacketTransfer.send();
recivedData = usbPacketTransfer.recive();
```

Comment: Is there any related code after the usb stuff? I don't know anything about usb on android but if there is anything dealing with the complete array after the usb stuff it might be a race condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move all of your network operations out of the main UI thread.  I would recommend using `AsyncTask` or `Thread` to do this.  Your network commands are blocking everything else from running which is why it only updates at the end.